# Repeat the value in column B until there is change occur in column A in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and have a query. I need the value repeated in column B until a change occur in column A.

Here's the sample Data:

```
A   B
18  1
18  0
18  0
24  2
24  0
24  0
24  0
10  3
10  0
10  0
```

How I want my output

```
Column A  Column B
18         1
18         1
18         1
18         1
24         2
24         2
10         3
10         3
10         3
10         3
```

Please help me thru this. Thank you

Comment: I think you can format values of data by 4 spaces before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) by `first` if need repeat first value of each group:

```
df['Column B'] = df.groupby('Column A')['Column B'].transform('first')
print (df)
   Column A  Column B
0        18         1
1        18         1
2        18         1
3        18         1
4        24         2
5        24         2
6        10         3
7        10         3
8        10         3
9        10         3
```

Another solution which dont depends of `Column A` - [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) `0` values by `NaN`, use forward filling by [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ffill.html) and last cast to `int`:

```
df['Column B'] = df['Column B'].replace(0,np.nan).ffill().astype(int)
print (df)
   Column A  Column B
0        18         1
1        18         1
2        18         1
3        18         1
4        24         2
5        24         2
6        10         3
7        10         3
8        10         3
9        10         3
```

Comment: I'm again facing the problem :  
Col A  Col B
  18         1
  18         0
  18         0
  18         0
  24         2
  24         0
  18         3
  18         0
  18         0
  18         0

Comment: Can you add new question with desired output? Thank you.

Comment: @Anagha - I think it is not good idea, the best is for another problem create new question. It is not complicated, but for me and for you it is better - you can accept new answer (maybe more answers) - get points and me too if my answer will be upvote.

Comment: because the most people check only new fresh question... What do you think?

Comment: Thank you, but why dont use second solution? `df['Column B'] = df['Column B'].replace(0,np.nan).ffill().astype(int)` ?

Comment: Thanks, the above code is not working. I have opened a new question as well