# One value for each df Column group

Tags: python, pandas

```
            A   B
0  2002-01-16  10
1  2002-01-16   7
2  2002-01-16   2
3  2002-01-16   8
4  2002-01-16   5
5  2002-01-17  54
6  2002-01-17   6
7  2002-01-17   2
```

I want to add a *C column* which contains the **first *Column B value* for each *Column A date group***. The output might be:

```
            A   B   C
0  2002-01-16  10  10
1  2002-01-16   7  10
2  2002-01-16   2  10
3  2002-01-16   8  10
4  2002-01-16   5  10
5  2002-01-17  54  54
6  2002-01-17   6  54
7  2002-01-17   2  54
```

I´ve tested with:

```
df["C"] = df.values[0][1]
```

But it doesn´t change the value for each *Column A date group*.

Thank you.

Comment: Think you're after: `df.groupby('A').B.transform('first')` ?

Comment: @JonClements this is perfect. Can you add it as an answer?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864398/repeat-the-value-in-column-b-until-there-is-change-occur-in-column-a-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can groupby column A, then use `.transform('first')` on column B to generate a series that has the first value of the group for all items in the group, eg:

```
df.loc[:, 'C'] = df.groupby('A').B.transform('first')
```

This'll make your example frame be:

```
            A   B   C
0  2002-01-16  10  10
1  2002-01-16   7  10
2  2002-01-16   2  10
3  2002-01-16   8  10
4  2002-01-16   5  10
5  2002-01-17  54  54
6  2002-01-17   6  54
7  2002-01-17   2  54
```

Comment: Or that - yes :)

Comment: Or simply this? `df['C'] = df.groupby('A').transform('first')`

Comment: @Bill yeah... if you want all columns not part of the group or if B is definitely the only column...