# Setting value to a shifted value using np.where in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working on a time-series. I have calculated high and low fractals using the code below. What i am trying to do is, if there's a fractal marked, keep it in each column until a new one occurs. I have tried to use `np.where` and it seems i am using it wrong way. Here is my code:

```
df['high_fractal'] = np.where((df['High']>df['High'].shift(-1)) & (df['High']>df['High'].shift(-2)) & (df['High']>df['High'].shift(1)) & (df['High']>df['High'].shift(2)) & (df['High'].shift(-2)), 1, 0)
df['low_fractal'] = np.where((df['Low']<df['Low'].shift(-1)) & (df['Low']<df['Low'].shift(-2)) & (df['Low']<df['Low'].shift(1)) & (df['Low']<df['Low'].shift(2)) & (df['Low'].shift(-2)), 1, 0)
df['lf'] = np.zeros((len(df)))
df['hf'] = np.zeros((len(df)))
df['lf'] = np.where(df['low_fractal']==1, df['Low'], df['lf'].shift(1))
df['hf'] = np.where(df['high_fractal']==1, df['High'], df['hf'].shift(1))
print(df[['Date', 'High', 'Low', 'lf', 'hf']].tail())

            Date    High     Low      lf      hf
10007 2018-08-06  1.1574  1.1527  1.1527  0.0000
10008 2018-08-07  1.1610  1.1547  0.0000  0.0000
10009 2018-08-08  1.1629  1.1571  0.0000  1.1629
10010 2018-08-09  1.1620  1.1525  0.0000  0.0000
10011 2018-08-10  1.1536  1.1388  0.0000  0.0000
```

columns lf and hf should contain previous lf and hf instead of zero. In this particular case all other lf values should be 1.1527 and hf (below 2018-08-08) should be 1.1629 How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864398/repeat-the-value-in-column-b-until-there-is-change-occur-in-column-a-in-python

Comment: ffill() works. Thank you but why doesn't this solution work?

Comment: I guess you just shift the original column with zeros and not the updated values in the last `np.where` statements.